# How to send a image with other parameters using retrofit?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I have successfully used retrofit for sending objects like this

```
@POST("/v2/createCustomer")
    void createCustomer(@Body Customer customer, Callback<Customer> callback);
```

Customer class is like this.

```
class Customer{
String name;
String address;
}
```

But i want another Parameter in customer object. That is to insert file. which is captured from mobile. To do this what else i want to change. Give one example

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the image to a `Base64` string and then append that to the `Customer` object as another attribute. A lot of tutorials are available online for it.